# change image button in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, avaudioplayer

I have an audio player in the tableView that works with the help of a button.  The question is: how to change the icon of a button when you click on it. I managed to change the icon but it does not work correctly And strongly slows down when I press 2 times the button.

**GIF how it work:**

[image]

```
var boolValue = false

class TableViewControllerAudioList: UIView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var avplayer:AVPlayer!




override func setNeedsDisplay() {
    super.setNeedsDisplay()


}



 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return modalsF.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellAudioList


    cell.name.text = modalsF[indexPath.row].AudioName
    cell.duration.text = "00:00"
    cell.number.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

    cell.playChange.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.playChange.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tickClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.tapAction = { (cell) in


   // self.player = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: "https:---.com" + modalsF[indexPath.row].UrlName! as NSString, type: "mp3")

    self.avplayer = self.pl(file: "https:---.com" + modalsF[indexPath.row].UrlName! as NSString)


       // self.play(tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row)

        }


     return cell
}



func tickClicked(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print(sender.tag)
    let cellTop = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as!TableViewCellAudioList

    if boolValue == false{
        cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        boolValue = true
    } else {
        cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        boolValue = false
    }
}

func pl(file:NSString) -> AVPlayer? {

    let url = URL(string: file as String)
    let avPlayer: AVPlayer?
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)



    if avPlayer?.rate == 0 {
        avPlayer?.play()
        avPlayer?.rate = 1.0

    } else if avPlayer?.rate == 1{

        avPlayer?.pause()

    }

    return avPlayer

}
```

TableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCellAudioList: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var duration: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playChange: UIButton!



var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
@IBAction func playAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    tapAction?(self) 
  }    
}
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Pass indexpath row to your button action and write button action in your view controller. Then access cell from row index in action and change button image like

 let cellTop = tblView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! TableViewCellAudioList

f boolValue == true{
       cell. playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    } else {
       cell. playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        boolValue = true
    }

Comment: @VibhaSingh  it's work only in first cell

Comment: You have to pass indexpath row to your action. I just mention row-0 at this place you have to mention your own cell numbers

Comment: @VibhaSingh Thank you very much, you helped me a lot,but there is one small problem, each 10 cell  is repeated

Comment: I guess this is cell Identifier issue.. For this I need to see code.

Comment: @VibhaSingh i refresh code

Comment: Dont write tap action in cell. Write it in viewcontroller.

Comment: @VibhaSingh how pass index path to viewController

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
cell.button = indexPath.Row
}

 func tickClicked(_ sender: UIButton!) {

 print(sender.tag)

let cellTop = tblView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! TableViewCellAudioList

 if boolValue == false
{
    boolValue = true
        } else {
            boolValue = false
        }}

Comment: @VibhaSingh it is not working. i refresh code

Comment: remove cell.tapAction = { (cell) in

Comment: cell.playChange.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.tickClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: @VibhaSingh He behaves even worse

Comment: Opps... can you write code of playAudio() action in tickClicked() function when your bool is false.

Comment: @VibhaSingh No, it takes data with modalsF [indexPath.row] .UrlName!

Comment: Not an isssue you can take same form modalsF [sender.tag]

Comment: @VibhaSingh ModalsF [indexPath.row] .UrlName!  pass a link to audio

Comment: self.avplayer = self.pl(file: "https:---.com" + modalsF[sender.tag].UrlName! as NSString)

Comment: @VibhaSingh it's not work, but i set image in cellForRowAt and it's work, but  cell don't save image when scroll

Comment: func tickClicked(_ sender: UIButton!)
    {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
        
        if (sender.isSelected)
        {
            NSLog("Selected")
            sender.isSelected = true
       }else
      {  sender.isSelected = false

}
}

Comment: @VibhaSingh it's not work

Comment: can you share demo code with just this tableview and playing audio? I tried all but not sure not what to answer

Comment: @VibhaSingh have you downloaded the project?

Comment: yes and working on it

Comment: @VibhaSingh  i download project. can you delete link?

Comment: Deleted Link.. Have you checked?

Comment: @VibhaSingh Thank you very much you really helped me. But I have 1 question for what is needed tableView.tableFooterView = UIView ()

Comment: This will remove unwanted empty cell from footer.

Comment: If you need any help in future related code or any logic then add me in Linkedin (Vibha singh / gangofv@gmail.com). I have total 6 yrs of experience in IOS (Swift / Objective C)..

Comment: @VibhaSingh I do not use Linkedin

Comment: @VibhaSingh I'm sorry, yesterday I was trying all day to do the same for UISlider but I did not succeed, how can I do the same for UISlider

Comment: Provide demo will make change in that. I deleted your demo from my system :(

Comment: @VibhaSingh  have you downloaded the project?

Comment: yes and working on that.. it will take some time as I have my some work. Max 2 hrs it will take

Comment: @VibhaSingh It does not work correctly

Comment: I checked it is working..What issue u r facing?

Comment: @VibhaSingh I added a gif in the question

Comment: @VibhaSingh slider not save current time a gif in the question

Comment: Will let you know about this after 2 hrs

Comment: @VibhaSingh I  apologize for being late

Comment: Actually I have not worked on that since working on some other freelancing project and not getting time to do this.

Comment: Did you solved this or not? Or still stuck ...

Comment: @VibhaSingh still stuck

Comment: @VibhaSingh it seems something broke the gif in question

Comment: I added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below Method and it will take some time to play

```
 func tickClicked(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print(sender.tag)

        // add me on linkdin from vibha singh for further help
        let cellTop = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as!TableViewCellAudioList

        // Check for current status of button selection
        let checkSelectedStatus = modalsF[sender.tag].isSelected
        let currentag = sender.tag

        if(checkSelectedStatus == "0")
        {
            modalsF[sender.tag].isSelected = "1"
             avPlayer?.cancelPendingPrerolls()


let _ = avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 0.1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        { [] (time) in

            // update slider
            let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer?.currentItem!.asset.duration)!)
            let someVal : Float = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(duration)
            modalsF[currentag].BarProgressVal = someVal
            print("Some val \(someVal)")
            print("Current tag \(currentag)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


            // If 0 then set 1 so that while table scroll it will not change value

             cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)


        } else
        {
            modalsF[sender.tag].isSelected = "0" //If 1 then set 0 so that while table scroll it will not change value
            cellTop.playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        }

        // this will play at a time one audio

        if(lastSelectedcount != 40000 && lastSelectedcount != sender.tag) {
            modalsF[lastSelectedcount].isSelected = "0"
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: It will take some time to play

Comment: can remove links for a project?

Comment: I am always available if u need any help in future.. also if u have any freelance project then I can work for that.. best luck

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem with slowing down is that you start playback in the same tap method. You read the whole file in memory before making `AVAudioPlayer` instance. This is slow, and is the most probably the source of your slowdown.

1. You don't need to load file into memory, you can play it from file -
   [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387281-init). I am not 100% sure how AVAudioPlayer works internally but it might reduce your slowdown.
2. In order to remove slowdown you can either start playing in separate thread or try to postpone playing from current runloop cycle with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1 /*seconds*/, execute: {`. This should allow UIKit to finish all redrawing operations and you should get fast change. *Dispatching after* could be the fast and dirty solution but you need to actually measure how much of slowdown you get by starting playing and decide if you can keep it in main thread.

EDIT: After discussion in comments and realising that you don't load file from disk but from internet.

You might want to take a look at AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer. Your problem is that you load the whole file from internet which is **VERY** slow in main thread. AVPlayer allows to play remote file via "streaming". With that you wouldn't have to wait for the whole file to download.

The other option is to predownload your files, but this is out of the scope for this question.

Comment: @lur did not help

Comment: @Vasya2014 could you try to comment out the code which creates and start the player and check if it gets your button to change image quickly?

Comment: @Vasya2014 well, then like I said in point 2 of my answer you might need to move playback start to another thread or somehow change the way you start playback. Apparently you playback start is very heavy, which slows down main thread significantly which in turn produces the delay.

Comment: @Vasya2014 I am sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: When using dispatcherQueue, nothing changes significantly

Comment: @Vasya2014 yes, because it doesn't move player init to another thread. If the init is really heavy it will hinder main thread and moving it around runloops will not help. You might need to start playing or at least load your data in background thread.

Comment: @Vasya2014 I am sorry, I missed that you load your file from the internet. You can check updated answer.

Comment: I know that I need to use avplayer I could not find anything about the avplayer in the tableview

Comment: @Vasya2014 I think you could start with just `let avPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: yourURL)` and then `avPlayer.play()`. There is no connection between players and tableviews.You can use AVPlayer in a similar way you use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: thank you, there is 1 bug if not difficult help, the gif in question

Comment: @Vasya2014 in general you shouldn't override one question with multiple followups. I propose you to make a new separate question about the other issue. Point me to it, I will take a look.